# Google App Engine + Spring + Domain Object Instance Security

Tags: java, security, spring, google-app-engine, spring-security

To the point, I was researching implementing security with Spring on Google App Engine which made me feel confident until looking at their implementation of domain ACL.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html

I was wondering if this would work in App Engine, and if there any resources/examples demonstrating a working application.

This is a bare bone example of Spring Security working on GAE, but without domain ACL, just basic authentication.

http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/02/spring-security-in-google-app-engine/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ACL just define a custom service, it have to work on GAE.

This should be a good start:
http://grzegorzborkowski.blogspot.com/2008/10/spring-security-acl-very-basic-tutorial.html